# Regex validation goes wrong - Java

Tags: java, regex

So I have this row of regex to check my input. There is an input because the else is activated but I can't find it.

```
Username: Donald
Password: 1234
Name: Donald
LastName: Muylle
Phone: 012121212
Address: Zeverstreet 12
City: Gestel
Job: Bar

if(txtUsername.getText().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]")
&& txtPassword.getText().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]") &&
txtName.getText().matches("[a-zA-Z]") && 
txtLastName.getText().matches("[a-zA-Z]") && 
txtPhone.getText().matches("[0-9]") &&
txtAddress.getText().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]") && 
txtCity.getText().matches("[a-zA-Z]") && 
txtJob.getText().contains("[a-zA-Z]")){
    // Code
} else {
    // Shows Alert
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to add `+` quantifier next to all the character classes like,

```
txtUsername.getText().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
                                          ^
```

So that, it would match one or more occurrences of the characters   given in the list. Without  `+`, it would match a single character only where the matches method must check for a match against the whole string. So this would end up in failure if the input contain more than one character.

Comment: For some weird reason, still showing my error. It didn't fix the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: It's an error button I made my self that just says 'Credentials not filled in correctly.'

Comment: it seems like error caused by some part of your program not the regex.

Comment: I already debugged all the rest and ended up in the regex because if I system.out.println('bla') in the ELSE part, it would show up, so that makes my attention go to the regex being a failure.

Comment: I think I found it, the last matches is 'contains' and not 'matches'. How did I get that :D Still thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

All your regular expressions match only strings of 1 char.
Modify all them adding a + symbol at the end.

So `[a-zA-Z0-9]` becomes `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, `[a-zA-Z]` becomes `[a-zA-Z]+` and so on.

The address regular expression `[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]` should be `[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+` with only one slash

Comment: For some weird reason, still showing my error. It didn't fix the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: There is also another problem in the address regular expression.

Comment: There is also another problem in the address regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You have `contains` in the last check. Replace it with `matches`.